# Why do we need Ajax/jQuery calling for colntroller method when we already have default functionality given by MVC?

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, asynchronous

Suppose in a sample application there is a SUBMIT button, and in FORM tag I've alreasdy set POST method. So when I click on submit button it'll automatically execute respective controller's action. This id already there in MVC. Then why do we need AJAX or jQuery for the same purpose, i.e. calling respective controller's action?

I know Ajax call would be asynchrounous, but other than that any other advantage?

Comment: If you want to redirect to another page when you submit, use a normal form submmit. If you want to stay on the same page (to perform other actions of update the DOM, using ajax improves performance because you do not need to reload the whole page)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I know Ajax call would be asynchrounous, but other than that any other advantage?

By doing AJAX calls, you can return a partial view content which you can use to update one part of the current page. With AJAX calls, you can do partial updates without reloading the whole page.